# What is the sssd equivalent for wbinfo

Tags: active-directory, redhat, sssd

In the past we used winbind to integrate our RedHat servers with the Active Directory, we switched to using realmd and sssd. winbind provides a tool wbinfo to query user/group properties.

e.g. wbinfo --uid-info id

Does sssd provide a similar tool ?

I installed sssd-tools but that seems to be a collection of tools to add/delete/modify users and groups.

I need to translate a uid provided by smbstatus into a username

Comment: I use wbinfo mainly to list all groups that are available... I don't think the answer "use getent and id" will cut it to replace wbinfo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably getent for user information en good old id:

```
$ getent passwd user2
user2:*:1076200005:1076200005:ipa user:/home/user2:/bin/sh
$ id user2
uid=1076200005(user2) gid=1076200005(user2) groups=1076200005(user2)
```

Used against a ipa server, no kerberos trusts with AD, but should work the same.

Comment: Thanks, I tested it and both `getent passwd` _uid_ and `id` _uid_ work